# Regarding Word Docs Edit and Save within the .NET Application (Angular + Asp.Net Core)

Tags: excel

1. Open MS Word within the Application
   2.User Shall able to edit the opened ms word copy
   3.The edited ms word copy should  save in server level after completion of editing activity.

Note: Please respond for these all given queries.

Thanks

I am expecting respond from stackover flow developer community.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.